# How to disable to price label?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

I am new in Magento and now I am trying to disable the price label on the product page. I tried to modify the `price.phtml`, but I can't find it out.

[image]

Chrome Inspect:

```
<div class="price-box" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
 <span class="regular-price" itemprop="price" id="product-price-123">
    <span style="color: #F51361; font-size: 31px; ">MOQ:</span>
    <span class="price">:41.00</span>
 </span>
```

How can I delete the label? Thx a lot...

Comment: I posted answer but it seems you need to remove currency sign?

Answer (score 2):

Go to this file: 
Custom THEME:

```
/app/design/frontend/NAMESPACE/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml
```

This is extended file of core file:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml
```

Line no: 36 is displaying code. You can Go to

```
<strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong>
```

You can delete above line and label will be deleted. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for late reply...I go into that file, but I can't see those code..I will post `attributes.phtml` on my question..Thx

Comment: Its attribute.phtml not attributeS.phtml . plz note its without S.  you will get code there.

Answer (score 1):

update code

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme name/template/catalog/product/price.phtml file
```

you find the word MOQ: and remove it from that file

Comment: That is the chrome inspect only...

Answer (score 1):

add this css code in your css file

this will hide the price lable and you dont need to change phtml file , simple solution for you.

```
.regular-price span:first-child {
    display :none;  
}
```